# How can I install ri and rdoc files for gems afterwards?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I normally don't need ri and rdoc, so I write in `~/.gemrc` like this.

```
install: --no-ri --no-rdoc
update: --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

I want to install them afterwards when I have time.
How can I install ri and rdoc files for installed gems afterwards?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
# See the relevant help.
gem help rdoc

# Generate rdoc and ri for the "foo" gem.
gem rdoc --ri foo

# Generate rdoc for all installed gems.
gem rdoc --all
```

Comment: Thanks! I could install with `gem rdoc --all --ri`.

Answer (score 1):

According to chapter 10 of the [RubyGems Command](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/10#page95) reference, you can use `gem rdoc` to install rdoc.

Here is an excerpt...

```
Usage: gem rdoc [args] [options]

  Options:
        --all                        Generate RDoc documentation for all installed gems
    -v, --version VERSION            Specify version of gem to rdoc

  Common Options:
        --source URL                 Use URL as the remote source for gems
    -p, --[no-]http-proxy [URL]      Use HTTP proxy for remote operations
    -h, --help                       Get help on this command
        --config-file FILE           Use this config file instead of default
        --backtrace                  Show stack backtrace on errors
        --debug                      Turn on Ruby debugging

  Arguments:
    GEMNAME          The gem to generate RDoc for (unless --all)

  Summary:
    Generates RDoc for pre-installed gems

  Defaults:
    --version '> 0.0.0'
```